# Whats the probability of all cups have been used?

Tags: probability, combinations

I brought 20 cups. I use 2 cups every morning, then I wash off and put them together.

What's the probability that all the cups have been used after $n$ days.

---

> For general, $\color{red}{k}$ balls in one box, take out $\color{red}l$ balls each time and mark them, then putback and disrupt.
>
> What's the probability of $\color{red}m$ balls have been marked after $\color{red}n$ times operation?

Comment: This is a variation on the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), in this case allowing you to draw more than one coupon at a time.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I found this: [A GENERALIZED COUPON COLLECTOR PROBLEM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.5608v2.pdf ), but I think the general case differs from this paper.

Comment: That paper indeed considers a different scenario, where the collector gets a choice of one coupon to keep (which makes it more complicated actually - I think yours is more straightforward). I finally got around to thinking about it, and I believe I have a solution, but since it's been over a month, and the question hasn't had that much interest shown in it by others, I wonder if you are still curious about it. The result isn't a simple formula - it's a combinatorial sum, similar to the case $l=1$, where that sums happens to be a Stirling number - but with $l>1$, it is slightly different.